# An inequality from Kato local smoothing effect

Tags: partial-differential-equations, distribution-theory, dispersive-pde

When I reading a book concerning the proof of Kato local smoothing effect, I'm confused by the following inequality:

$$\int_{\mathbb{R}^{d}}\int_{\mathbb{R}^{d}}\hat{a}(\eta-\xi){\color{red}{\delta(|\eta|^{2}-|\xi|^{2})|\xi|^{1/2}|\eta|^{1/2}}}\hat{f}(\xi)\overline{\hat{f}(\eta)}d\xi d\eta=\int_{\mathbb{R}^{d}}\int_{\mathbb{R}^{d}}\hat{a}(\eta-\xi)\color{red}{\delta(|\eta|-|\xi|)\frac{|\xi|^{1/2}|\eta|^{1/2}}{|\xi|+|\eta|}}\hat{f}(\xi)\overline{\hat{f}(\eta)}d\xi d\eta$$
I want to know the red part of the above identity. The $\delta$ in above formula means Dirac generalization function, i.e. a distribution!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the support of the measure $\delta(\lvert\xi\rvert^2-\lvert\eta\rvert^2)$, you have $\lvert \xi\rvert=\lvert\eta\rvert$. Moreover, $\delta$ is $-1$ homogeneous, meaning that $\delta(\lambda t)=\lambda^{-1}\delta(t)$ for all $\lambda>0$. The above formula follows from these two properties.

More precisely, the $d\eta$ part of your double integral reads
$$\begin{split}
\int_{\mathbb R^d} \delta(\lvert\xi\rvert^2-\lvert\eta\rvert^2)F(\eta)\, d\eta&= \int_{\mathbb R^d}\delta ((\lvert\xi\rvert -\lvert \eta\rvert)(\lvert\xi\rvert +\lvert \eta\rvert)) F(\eta)\, d\eta \\&= \int_{\mathbb R^d}\frac{\delta (\lvert\xi\rvert -\lvert \eta\rvert)}{2\lvert \xi\rvert} F(\eta)\, d\eta=\int_{\mathbb R^d}\frac{\delta (\lvert\xi\rvert -\lvert \eta\rvert)}{\lvert \xi\rvert+\lvert\eta\rvert} F(\eta)\, d\eta,
\end{split}$$
for a certain function $F(\eta)$. Multiplying by the remaining factors, which are functions of $\xi$, and integrating against $d\xi$ you get the desired formula.

Comment: Thank you for your kindness and patient explanation!!!! I don't realized the fact that $\delta$ is $-1$ homogeneous, I study nonlinear dispersive equation by myself only and I meet a series of difficulties. Your answer is invaluable and priceless for me!

Comment: In addition, do you know how to learn nonlinear dispersive equation step by step without too much difficulties? Are there any material you commend?

Comment: In your answer, $\int\frac{\delta(|\xi|-|\delta|)}{2|\xi|}F(\eta)d\eta$, what does $2|\xi|$ come from? Does it come from the fact that the property of Dirac function that $|\xi|=|\eta|$?

Comment: Ok, let me write $a=\lvert \xi\rvert, b=\lvert \eta\rvert$ to save time writing. This is the chain of identities: $\delta(a^2-b^2)=\delta((a-b)(a+b))=\frac{\delta(a-b)}{a+b}$. Here I used the $-1$ homogeneity of $\delta$. What I wrote above is a way of making this principle rigorous.

Comment: @monotoneoperator: "do you know how to learn nonlinear dispersive equation step by step without too much difficulties?" No. You will need to suffer with this stuff, it is inevitable. There is a huge literature and a big part of it is really technical and poorly written. Painful reads. Try solving problems yourself rather than just reading other people's writing.

Comment: Thank you for your comment about my confusion, I get your idea!

Comment: That is to say, I have to struggle to settle some difficult problem in nonlinear dispersive equation. "Try solving problems yourself rather than just reading other people's writing" your advice is very felicitously and meaningful!